# when does a change in php.ini take place in php-core?

Tags: php

If i make changes in php-ini:

when does php react?

is it possible, that I get other data in phpinfo()
than php realy uses?

Comment: @anubhava: not if you're using PHP as an Apache module

Comment: [Please don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP as an Apache module, you will have to restart the httpd service to have PHP re-read php.ini, or changes will not be taken into account.

From this [PHP manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

> The configuration file (php.ini) is read when PHP starts up. For the server module versions of PHP, this happens only once when the web server is started. For the CGI and CLI versions, it happens on every invocation.